# Create exemption for htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm running a CollectiveAccess cataloging system with a front-end gallery called Pawtucket. I want my domain to redirect to the Pawtucket landing page, which it does just fine, but now I can't access my cataloging back-end. Basically, I want to create an exemption to the 301 redirect if I type in "catalog" before my domain.

Here is what the .htaccess file looks in my root directory:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://example.net/pawtucket/index.php
```

I want something that allows me to make an exemption for this redirect if the request comes from `catalog.example.net`

Is that possible? Is there a better route? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it with rewrite...

If by "Coming From" you mean that they were previously at a page on `catalog.example.net`, then you want to use REFERRER:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !catalog\.example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://example.net/pawtucket/index.php [R=301]
```

However, if by "Coming From" you mean that the page they are CURRENTLY ON is on `catalog.exampe.net` then you want to use HOST (thanks, @CBroe):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !catalog\.example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://example.net/pawtucket/index.php [R=301]
```

The first line gives the condition, and the second gives the redirect. I have `\.` instead of `.` because those particular pieces are regular expressions, and `.` means "any character"

The [NC] means not case sensitive.

...I think that should do it. Maybe? Give it a try :)

Comment: I think that is probably the wrong interpretation of “request comes from”, I think they are using a subdomain to access their backend. If that’s the case, then this should check on the request host name, not the referrer.

Comment: @CBroe, I think you're right. I'll update the answer